# Excel: Two different custom format into one cell

Tags: excel, formatting

How to concatenate two different custom format into one cell.

1: [>10 numbers]0##"/"###-##-## Example: 061/1111-22-33

2: [<10 numbers]0##"/"###-### Example: 061/111-222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that

```
[>999999999]"0"#"/"####-##-##;[<=999999999]"0"##"/"###-###
```

[image]

Comment: I do not get correct result Example 1: 061/111-222 Example 2: 061/1111-22-33

Answer (score 1):

Just create two conditional formatting rules:

- Select the specific cell, or whole column if you want (in this example `A1`)
- Click on Conditional formatting button -> New rule
- Use formula: `=LEN(A1)>=10`
- Use custom format: `0##"/"###-##-##`

Repeat the process for formula:

- `=LEN(A1)<10` with custom format `0##"/"###-###`

Comment: second Conditional working primary Conditional give me result: 611/111-22-33 My goal is: 061/1111-22-33

Comment: They are the formatting rules you provided though ;)

Comment: How to fix your custom formating to get 061/1111-22-33 excel returns me: 611/111-22-33

Comment: Then what about, `0##"/"####-##-##`